# convert json from one format to other , values as a object

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a json in form of `[{"user":"xyz","type":"Accounts"}]` want to convert into `[{"user":xyz,"type":Accounts}]` I want to make a json object similar to first one with little change in value , value should be without quotes "".
i am looking for

```
[PollQuestionDTO [questionId=null, articleId=null, questionText=India have applied a defibrillator to this series 1, pollType=SINGLE_ANSWER, selectedOptionIds=[], pollOptionList=[PollOptionDTO [optionId=0, questionId=0, optionText=India have applied a defibrillator to this series 2, selectedByUser=N, createdDate=null, modifiedDate=null], PollOptionDTO [optionId=0, questionId=0, optionText=India have applied a defibrillator to this series 3, selectedByUser=N, createdDate=null, modifiedDate=null], PollOptionDTO [optionId=0, questionId=0, optionText=India have applied a defibrillator to this series 4, selectedByUser=N, createdDate=null, modifiedDate=null], PollOptionDTO [optionId=0, questionId=0, optionText=India have applied a defibrillator to this series 5, selectedByUser=N, createdDate=null, modifiedDate=null], PollOptionDTO [optionId=0, questionId=0, optionText=India have applied a defibrillator to this series 6, selectedByUser=N, createdDate=null, modifiedDate=null]], pollId=null], PollQuestionDTO [questionId=null, articleId=null, questionText=India have applied a defibrillator to this series text., pollType=SINGLE_ANSWER, selectedOptionIds=[], pollOptionList=[PollOptionDTO [optionId=0, questionId=0, optionText=India have applied a defibrillator to this series 111, selectedByUser=N, createdDate=null, modifiedDate=null], PollOptionDTO [optionId=0, questionId=0, optionText=India have applied a defibrillator to this series 222, selectedByUser=N, createdDate=null, modifiedDate=null], PollOptionDTO [optionId=0, questionId=0, optionText=India have applied a defibrillator to this series 333, selectedByUser=N, createdDate=null, modifiedDate=null], PollOptionDTO [optionId=0, questionId=0, optionText=India have applied a defibrillator to this series 444, selectedByUser=N, createdDate=null, modifiedDate=null], PollOptionDTO [optionId=0, questionId=0, optionText=India have applied a defibrillator to this series 555, selectedByUser=N, createdDate=null, modifiedDate=null]], pollId=null], PollQuestionDTO [questionId=null, articleId=null, questionText=India have applied a defibrillator to this series text text data., pollType=SINGLE_ANSWER, selectedOptionIds=[], pollOptionList=[PollOptionDTO [optionId=0, questionId=0, optionText=India have applied a defibrillator to this series 122, selectedByUser=N, createdDate=null, modifiedDate=null], PollOptionDTO [optionId=0, questionId=0, optionText=India have applied a defibrillator to this series 33, selectedByUser=N, createdDate=null, modifiedDate=null], PollOptionDTO [optionId=0, questionId=0, optionText=India have applied a defibrillator to this series 444, selectedByUser=N, createdDate=null, modifiedDate=null], PollOptionDTO [optionId=0, questionId=0, optionText=India have applied a defibrillator to this series nnn, selectedByUser=N, createdDate=null, modifiedDate=null], PollOptionDTO [optionId=0, questionId=0, optionText=India have applied a defibrillator to this seriesb de, selectedByUser=N, createdDate=null, modifiedDate=null]], pollId=null]]
```

kind of json.however i m having in form of like ,[{"user":"xyz","type":"Accounts"}]

Comment: `[{"user":xyz,"type":Accounts}]` isn't valid JSON. You need the quotes because `xyz` and `Accounts` are strings. But the quotes are only part of the *syntax*, they're not part of the actual *values*. If you're seeing quotes in the *values* after you parse the JSON then there is something else going on - please [edit] your question to show the relevant code. *"I want to make a json object"* - [there ain't no such thing](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: @nnnnnn sir plz see the edit.

Comment: Use `JSON.parse`?

Comment: don't work directly with JSON strings ... parse the JSON .. work with the object, then stringify (i.e. convert to JSON string) the modified object

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to decode the JSON and fill in variables by binding data to it?

```js
// JSON string to decode.
var jsonStr = '[{ "user": "xyz", "type": "Accounts" }]';
// Variables to be used as replacements.
var variableData = {
  Accounts : { class : 'Accounts' }
};

function parseJson(json, data) {
  var arr = JSON.parse(json);
  arr.forEach(item => {
    for (var key in item) {
      if (data[item[key]]) {
        item[key] = data[item[key]];
      }
    }
  });
  return arr;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(parseJson(jsonStr, variableData), null, 2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```